# Attribute Route with constraint works locally but fails when deployed

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

I have a simple attribute route with three different path segments:

```
[HttpGet]
[GET("v{version:int}/{category}/{service}")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RouteMessage(
    string category, string service, int version = 1)
{
}
```

While the routing works when developing locally, it fails (404) when I deploy it to an IIS server.

The URL that fails:

```
http://example.com/v1/search/products?client=test
```

I'm certain it's not an IIS issue because I can still access the service using non-attribute routing (note that even though `v1` isn't an int, the parameter itself has a default value):

```
http://example.com/api/route/?version=v1&category=search&service=products&client=test
```

I've installed [Route Debugging](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/) and, as expected, my route does *not* match the attribute route even though it should.

The app-relative path is listed as `~/v1/search/products`, which should match the url format `v{version}/{category}/{service}` ("version" is also correctly listed with an int route constraint).

[Here's an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF3QZ.png) with the full debug info in case it helps.

[image: []

Comment: Do you see any error details in the 404 response?

Comment: I do not. It's a generic 404 page, *not* a web api response: *Server Error / 404 - File or directory not found. / The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.*

Comment: Can you share in which order are you registering your routes?

Comment: I'm using the default MapHttpRoute provided by WebApi. Attribute routing added a call to MapHttpAttributeRoutes *before* the WebApi route, so it should come first. I only have one Attribute Route, the one listed above. I'm fairly certain that the image I attached lists the routes in order too.

Comment: The thing which i want to get cleared about is whether you are calling `config.Routes.MapHttpAttributeRoutes` or `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes`...this is because you seem to be using `AttributeRouting.Net` nuget package(based on your `GET` attribute) and not Web API's in-build attribute routing...so if you are mistakenly calling `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes` (which belongs to webapi), then your attribute route is never created in the route table resulting in 404...i know you are mentioning that it works locally, but i want to make sure first..

Comment: I was calling `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes`, not `config.Routes.MapHttpAttributeRoutes`. I will try using the other way and see if it helps.

Comment: Actually, I'm wrong. `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes` was there, but AttributeRouting also added its own routing in a separate file using `WebActivator`. https://gist.github.com/nemec/b60dc023e1d5af905b4b

Comment: To confirm, you still see the issue..right? Finally, just to make sure that the problem is not with WebActivator(as i have seen users complaining similary here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115497/webactivator-preapplicationstartmethod-does-not-work), can you explicitly call `config.Routes.MapHttpAttributes()` and see if things still work?

Comment: I did try explicitly calling it and still had the issue, but I ended up switching to the built-in WebApi routing. It's working fine now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Kiran Challa I realized that, although similar, the built-in [WebAPI attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) is not the same as `AttributeRouting.WebApi`. I switched to the built-in routing and it all works fine now.